# Sharing lambda layers across different region or different account

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation, aws-codecommit, aws-lambda-layers

I have a lambda layer named "function.zip" in code commit and in s3 bucket . Cloudformation works fine without any issue since i'm using the function.zip  saved in s3 and using s3 uri as content uri in CFT for "AWS::Serverless::LayerVersion". Since i am using the s3 uri, "function.zip" will be available only in one region(ohio).
I want this fuction.zip be available in all the region in same account. Will it be possible to access the "function.zip" from all the region using codecommit by keeping "AWS::Serverless::LayerVersion" content uri in Cloudformation as codecommit rather than using s3uri. If you could share the sample template and how are you accessing it by saving it in codecommit that would be helpful.